# Why does Python's MIMEMultipart generate attachment filenames with newlines?

Tags: python, mime

I am sending an email with an attachment, and that attachment has a long filename. Why does it get corrupted with newlines, and what part of the system is supposed to know these newlines should be removed?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.utils import formatdate

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['To'] = 'a@example.com'
msg['From'] = 'b@example.com'
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg.attach(MIMEText('abc'))

attachment_name = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.txt'
part = MIMEApplication("sometext", Name=attachment_name)
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % attachment_name
msg.attach(part)

print msg.as_string()
```

Gives me:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1448866158=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: subject
To: a@example.com
From: b@example.com
Date: Sat, 20 Jan 2018 13:11:42 -0500

--===============1448866158==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

abc
--===============1448866158==
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
 Name="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.txt"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.txt"

c29tZXRleHQ=
--===============1448866158==--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling of long header fields is defined in [section 2.2.3 of RFC 2822 "Internet Message Format"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3). That section survives unchanged in an obsoleting [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3).

> 2.2.3. Long Header Fields
>
> Each header field is logically a single line of characters comprising
> the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For convenience
> however, and to deal with the 998/78 character limitations per line,
> the field body portion of a header field can be split into a multiple
> line representation; this is called "folding".  The general rule is
> that wherever this standard allows for folding white space (not simply
> WSP characters), a CRLF may be inserted before any WSP.  For example,
> the header field:
>
> ```
> Subject: This is a test
> ```
>
> can be represented as:
>
> ```
> Subject: This
>  is a test
> ```
>
> Note: Though structured field bodies are defined in such a way that
> folding can take place between many of the lexical tokens (and even
> within some of the lexical tokens), folding SHOULD be limited to
> placing the CRLF at higher-level syntactic breaks.  For instance, if a
> field body is defined as comma-separated values, it is recommended
> that folding occur after the comma separating the structured items in
> preference to other places where the field could be folded, even if it
> is allowed elsewhere.
>
> **The process of moving from this folded multiple-line representation of
> a header field to its single line representation is called
> "unfolding". Unfolding is accomplished by simply removing any CRLF
> that is immediately followed by WSP.  Each header field should be
> treated in its unfolded form for further syntactic and semantic
> evaluation.**

Answer (score 2):

As Leon's answer explains, Python is implementing the folding algorithm defined in the RFCs.

In Python 2, you can use an `email.generator.Generator` instance to give you control over the maximum header length; from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string):

> For more flexibility, instantiate a Generator instance and use its flatten() method directly. For example:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
from email.generator import Generator
fp = StringIO()
g = Generator(fp, mangle_from_=False, maxheaderlen=60)
g.flatten(msg)
text = fp.getvalue()
```

(setting maxheaderlen to zero will prevent folding of long header lines in almost all cases).

In Python 3.5, the maxheaderlen argument is exposed in `email.message.Message.as_string`'s [signature](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.as_string), so

`print(msg.as_string(maxheaderlen=256))`

is possible. `maxheaderlen` is zero by default, so header lines are not wrapeed unless a value is provided.

In Python 3.6, `maxheaderlen` is exposed in `email.message.EmailMessage.as_string`'s [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.as_string) (note this is a different class).  `maxheaderlen` now defaults to `None`: header lines wrap at 78 characters unless a value is specified.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great digest on how to make the sender stop folding!